# How Do I Send My Client The Source Code To The App?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, export, apk

I just finished working on an app for a client and now I want to hand over the source code and everything else. I know I could generate an .apk and send him that but would he be able to open it on Android Studio and start working on it? How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Android Studio go to `File` -> `Close Project`.
Then copy the folder with your project from your workspace and send it to your client.
When he will receive the Project Folder all he need to do is:

- Open Android Studio
- Go to `File` -> `Open` and Import this project into his workspace